# Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop (not working with suggestions already given)

Tags: login

Added:
What worked was:
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

---

I tried what is written here: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

The first answer didn't worked. Some other ones I can't try them as I can't connect to the internet as I can't access to the network manager and some of suggestions are about editing the profile documents: the command lines for the terminal are not given and I don't know them. I hope you can help me.

Comment: I can't enter as root, neither as guest

Comment: U just uninstalled wifi driver...! And dont mark question as solved in title...write answer here in Answer section